# Server bandwidth issues, sending packets to China

Tags: bandwidth

### Can I solve this issue with IPtables?

I have come here as a last ditch effort to figure out what is going on. About a year ago I had my Minecraft server running out of my basement for me and my cousins, well about 2-3 months in I started getting all sorts of misc. web traffic whenever I would try to browse the internet on any device. So I unplugged and thought it was related to the browser compromises that had surfaced during the time or the server was compramised.

Now I have brought my server back online, updated the os and got everything running good again. Now two days after I started it back up I am getting a new issue where my entire network is drained of bandwidth. I thought that maybe there was a connection issue so I replaced Ethernet cables, seemed to fix the issue. I continued to have the server running and then the bandwidth got hogged so bad that it interfered with ATT u-verse tv streaming. I panicked very quickly and unplugged my server. Everything went back to normal after I unplugged. I started to investigate and now I have wireshark on my laptop and I fired back up my server to run IPtraf, which reveled some troubling results. Wireshark only showed the SSH packets between my laptop and server.

---

However the IPtraf reveled some startling traffic.

A few different IP's

```
61.174.48.17

115.231.17.13
```

These show up under TCP connections, both trace back to China in google searches.

---

Then on the bottom of IPtraf I have a bunch of UDP packets being sent to these IP's

```
120.52.32.51:53

183.57.154.252:53

180.153.23.102:53
```

each transaction rotates between one of these three IPs note: they all are port 53, WHY?
Also with each transaction the port it originates from on my server is unique each time.
Here an example of what the output looks like:

```
UDP (63 bytes) from 192.168.1.113:61900 to 183.57.154.252:53 on eth0                                                                                                 |
| UDP (63 bytes) from 192.168.1.113:18418 to 120.52.32.51:53 on eth0                                                                                                   |
| UDP (63 bytes) from 192.168.1.113:34175 to 61.240.144.116:53 on eth0                                                                                                 |
| UDP (63 bytes) from 192.168.1.113:30753 to 180.153.235.102:53 on eth0                                                                                                |
| UDP (63 bytes) from 192.168.1.113:42773 to 120.52.32.51:53 on eth0                                                                                                   |
| UDP (63 bytes) from 192.168.1.113:37734 to 61.240.144.116:53 on eth0                                                                                                 |
| UDP (63 bytes) from 192.168.1.113:38539 to 180.153.235.102:53 on eth0                                                                                                |
| UDP (63 bytes) from 192.168.1.113:25027 to 120.52.32.51:53 on eth0                                                                                                   |
| UDP (63 bytes) from 192.168.1.113:64958 to 183.57.154.252:53 on eth0                                                                                                 |
| UDP (63 bytes) from 192.168.1.113:51127 to 180.153.235.102:53 on eth0                                                                                                |
| UDP (63 bytes) from 192.168.1.113:34697 to 120.52.32.51:53 on eth0                                                                                                   |
| UDP (63 bytes) from 192.168.1.113:21752 to 183.57.154.252:53 on eth0                                                                                                 |
| UDP (63 bytes) from 192.168.1.113:45880 to 180.153.235.102:53 on eth0
```

Please help I have 10's of hours poured into configuring this server, and I would really like to rescue it, no matter how much more time I have to spend on it.

Comment: What is the operating system that this "server" is running on?  I am wondering why you did not use GUI tools in the OS itself, to discover what actual programs it is that is using bandwidth, and connecting to suspicious locations?  Wireshark is all cool and neets and stuff , but dont you have a way to trace first what is the source of the connections on your side?

Comment: The server(2x Xeon, 12 gb RAM) is running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, since the update.  I did run IPtraf and listed the some of the results above, is there anything else I can run to get a more detailed log? Wireshark doesn't seem to grab traffic between my server and the world, I was just letting everyone know it is an available tool if they had a solution that involved it.

Comment: I was running the server very unsecured, recently I have disabled SU log in on SSH, changed to SSH 2, and changed passwords, and the SSH port above port 1024. The problem still exsists, I have been doing some research on IPtables, the provided firewall, but I don't know if It can help now.